# 2D array, inequalities and where function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If given an array like

```
a = array([[2,4,9,8,473],[54,7,24,19,20]])
```

then how can I write the indexes of the array which are between values x and y?

currently I've got:

```
where(5 > a > 10)
```

if will however give an output if I say for example:

```
where(a > 5)
```

but the where function doesn't take this command and once it will it should output a 2 one dimensional array, is there a way to easily stack them?

Comment: You mean `5 < a < 10`, right? There aren't many values that are smaller than `5` but larger than `10`.

Comment: The double sided comparison only works for scalar values.  With an array it gives a ValueError (because of a short circuiting `and` test).  I elaborate on that in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42802950/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical operator `&`(and) `|` (or) to chain different conditions together, so for your case, you can do:

```
np.where((a > 5) & (a < 10))

# (array([0, 0, 1]), array([2, 3, 1]))
# here np.where gives a tuple, the first element of which gives the row index, while the 
# second element gives the corresponding column index
```

If you want the indices to be an array where each row represents an element, you can stack them:

```
np.stack(np.where((a > 5) & (a < 10)), axis=-1)
# array([[0, 2],
#        [0, 3],
#        [1, 1]])
```

Or as @Divakar commented use `np.argwhere((a > 5) & (a < 10))`.

Comment: Yes, that gives the indices I need. Is there a way to combine those two now?

Comment: Simpler with `np.argwhere()`.

Comment: @Divakar Exactly. Didn't know that.

Comment: `argwhere(...)` is just `return np.transpose(where(...))`.  So `transpose` is doing the same job as that `stack` (though I expect strides and order will be different).

Answer (score 0):

you have two indexes that you need to specify, one for which inner array you are referencing and the other for what actual member of that array you are referring to